# Adding ubuntu server to our Windows AD

Tags: networking, server, samba

I have a Windows Server 2016 controlling a domain of 3 PCs which run Windows 10 and share a laser printer.  All seems to be working well.  I have an Ubuntu server with plenty of spare capacity on its HDD.  Can anyone tell me if I can bind this Ubuntu server (17.04) to my Windows domain so that the Windows 10 PC clients can share the Ubuntu Servers's resources (mainly its HDD and print services)?
If it is possible, can you advise me on where to find a a good guide to follow to allow me to get this working?  I am new to this level of Ubuntu networking although I have a little experience in basic Ubuntu scripts and use of CLI commands of the Ubuntu Server 
Many thanks 
Neal T

Answer (score 0):

You will have to install samba and to configure it as a 'Domain Member'.  Full documentation is beyond the scope of an answer on askUbuntu.

I advise you to consult the offical site of [samba](https://samba.org), specifically the part about 'Learning samba' (see for instance, the Wiki part [on how to configure samba as a domain member.](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_Samba_as_a_Domain_Member)

Comment: I have tried to work my way through "how to configure samba as a domain member".  After following the guide, I find that I can now wbinfo -n AD users name and successfully get their RID but if I wbinfo -R that rid I fail to get an answer the query.  Got any ideas? Neal

Comment: Also wbinfo -u lists all my windows server 2016 AD users and wbinfo -g lists all my AD groups.  I think this means a good part of the installation is working as it should.  nslookup myADserver.mydomain gives the correct IP of 1921.68.xxx.yyy and nslookup 192.168.xxx.yyy returns the correct Server name

Comment: Good to see you are on the right track.  I have no idea about your wbinfo question, though.

Comment: Been following the Wiki "How to configure samba as a domain member.  All good up to the point where I test the system as below. 
When I run "getent passwd demo01" nothing happens. No error message or screen prompt. 
The libnss_winbind library enables you to look up domain users and groups. For example:
To look up the domain user demo01:
# getent passwd demo01
demo01:*:10000:10000:demo01:/home/demo01:/bin/bash
To look up the domain group Domain Users:
# getent group "Domain Users"
domain users:x:10000:
These commands do nothing - has anyone any ideas??